# Create a UI for editing Java object properties in a hierarchy of object

Tags: java

I have a class named `DataClass` and this class has a number of instance variables of other classes in its fields. So we have an object hierarchy. All of the leaves in this hierarchy are String. I want to create a simple UI to create and edit for such a hierarchy in Java. is there any component(s) that I can use for this?

I want to have something like a tree table in to show the hierarchy, and within that user can add or edit properties.

Something similar to the right panel of the following UI:

[image]

My final purpose is to let the user create this hierarchy and export it as an `XML` document.

Comment: You haven’t specified which UI library you plan to use.  If you’re using JavaFX, there is [a class for that](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html).

Comment: UI library/framework does not matter. I want the fastest way.tnx

Comment: JavaFX is likely to be faster than hunting down a third party tree table for Swing.  I recommend reading [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/) if you aren’t familiar with it.

Comment: `TreeTableView` seems great!. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you generate an XML Schema from your object? Then there are many solutions that will allow you to write XML files with auto-completion and validation for your XML Schema.

You can also generate a Swing UI from an XML Schema with:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxe/

Another interesting approach is using NakedObjects, now Apache ISIS to generate a complete Web UI + Database schema from a domain class hierarchy: http://isis.apache.org/

Comment: yes. I want to convert this hierarchy to xml.  but this is not important at all. I just need a property editor.

Comment: actually no! I don't need Schema and validation. I want something ready. don't want to spend time for this.

Comment: and I need to process this hierarchy and edit it in my code before generating xml. in fact I need to add some other xml elements based on user defined data.

Comment: Seems like you're going to need to do actual frontend development. No free lunch :-(

Comment: I thought that is a very common GUI Component (lots of apps have this kind of components like eclipse, IntelliJ NetBeans Matlab ...), and maybe there is a ready to use component.